# Count paths from one point to another in array recursion without repeating a cell

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, maze

I need to calculate the number of paths from one cell to another in the array when I can move right,left,down or up from every cell(within the array bounds).

How can I avoid repeating a cell that I already passed while I'm checking a path? There is also another rule:

> You can't use another array, loops and static variables.

How can I continue from here?

My recursion functions:

```
public static int calcPath(int [][] a, int currentx, int currenty, int destx, int desty)
{
    if (currentx == destx && currenty == desty)
        return 1;
    if(!bounds(a,currentx,currenty)) // if the cell isnt in the array bounds
        return 0;

    return  calcPath(math,currentx+1,currenty,destx,desty) +
             calcPath(math,currentx-1,currenty,destx,desty)+
              calcPath(math,currentx,currenty+1,destx,desty)+
               calcPath(math,currentx,currenty-1,destx,desty);
}
```

Comment: it might help me  avoid repeating going back to the last cell but I still might repeat one time a cell that i already passed if I move on a circle path (right down left up).

Answer (score 0):

Pass around a Set of cell already visited. The best way to do that would be to create a class that encapsulates the x and y if a cell and implement an equals() method that compares coordinates. However, you could "hack" it by crating a single unuque value for the two values.

The hack version would look like:

```
public static int calcPath(int [][] a, int currentx, int currenty, int destx, int desty, Set<Integer> visited) {
    int key = 1000 * currentx + currenty; // unique for x, y
    if (visited.contais(key))
        return 0;
    if (currentx == destx && currenty == desty)
        return 1;
    if(!bounds(a,currentx,currenty)) // if the cell isnt in the array bounds
        return 0;
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(visited);
    s.add(key);
    return  calcPath(math,currentx+1,currenty,destx,desty,s) +
         calcPath(math,currentx-1,currenty,destx,desty,s)+
          calcPath(math,currentx,currenty+1,destx,desty,s)+
           calcPath(math,currentx,currenty-1,destx,desty,s);
}
```

Note that you must create a new set when recursing so you don't pollute the callers heap.

For the initial call, pass in an empty Set.

Comment: the key formula need to be 1000*currentx + currenty or am i wrong ?

Comment: @marie I didn't look that closely, so you could be right. It also may not matter which is checked!

Comment: but if i use the function contains it means that i use loops because this function is based on loops isnt it ?

Comment: No, a HashSet uses hash lookup, which has O(1) speed (extremely fast!)

Comment: another question, why do you initialize the hashset again in the function ? why wont you add the key to the visited hashset and send that set in the recursion?

Comment: I have a problem in the function you wrote, It doesnt count pathes that have common cells. For example if i have both pathes : (0,0)->(0,1)-<1,1)-<(1,2) and (0,0)->(1,0)->(1,1)->(1,2) it wont cont the second path because i already passed the cell 1,1

Comment: I passed in a new set each call so changes to it made in a recursive call do not affect subsequent calls (for the other following directions). This allows backtracking to attempt consuming the same cell via a different path.

Comment: but when i run it i have a stackoverflowerror because every time i create a new set of keys that has only one unique key and therefor i`m stuck on a cricle path forever..

Comment: @mariel regarding your last comment and a previous one about using the "current" coordinates... Having read your code more carefully, the key should be built from currentx and currenty. See edited code - try it now.

Comment: It works :) :) : but i think that there are to many paths :/ i think something is wrong